# Use the maximum value from each element from one column to repeat other elements from other column

Tags: mysql

I have to do this table and I have to use 2 table to do it. I have a code that I don't understand why I don't get it right.

Table that I need to do:

-- Aquario (nome)

```
insert into Aquario values ('Vasco da Gama');
insert into Aquario values ('Bartolomeu Dias');
insert into Aquario values ('Bartolomeu Dias');
insert into Aquario values ('Infante D.Henrique');
insert into Aquario values ('Infante D.Henrique');
insert into Aquario values ('Infante D.Henrique');
insert into Aquario values ('Bartolomeu Dias');
insert into Aquario values ('Infante D.Henrique');
```

Tables that I need to use :

```
-- Aquario(id_aquario, localizacao, nome)

    insert into Aquario values (1,'NO','Vasco da Gama');
    insert into Aquario values (2,'N','Bartolomeu Dias');
    insert into Aquario values (3,'S','Infante D.Henrique');

-- Especime(id_especie,id_especime,nome_personalizado,id_aquario) 

    insert into Especime values (1,1,'Amalia',1);
    insert into Especime values (1,2,'Eusebio',2);
    insert into Especime values (1,3,'Marisa',2);
    insert into Especime values (1,4,'Cristiano',3);
    insert into Especime values (3,1,'Romeu',3);
    insert into Especime values (3,2,'Julieta',3);
```

Code that I have:

```
select A.nome
from Aquario A, Especime Espe
where (select min(Espe2.id_especime) 
       from Especime Espe2 
       where A.id_aquario = Espe2.id_aquario);
```

Comment: Sorry but I do not have the slightest idea what you want/need. You give a SELECT-Statement and want INSERTs? In your SELECT you should compare your subselect against something.

Comment: I have 3 " Aquarios " and each one have an id ( id_aquario ) , each aquario have an id_especime in " Especime " table , and i want to get the max id_especime number for each aquario and get the name of that aquario repeted. For example , when id_aquario = 3 , and we go Especime table , we see that max(id_especime) related with id_aquario = 3 is 4 , so the name of that aquario will be repeted 4 times.